# Python Shelve like requirement

Tags: python

I want to store some kind of persistent tracking to my application. Like for example ,

application.py supports 3 arguments, --firstarg --secondarg --thirdarg.

user can execute application.py using either one of the argument. I want to provide a feature where in user can track that he has already completed running the firstarg. In order to achieve this, i wanted to store a file called status.log, where the tracker will be stored.

Initially, status.log has

firstarg : 0
secondarg : 0
thirdarg : 0

once the user executes the first arg, it should turn the line , firstarg : 1

so when users wants, he can check if he has already completed running the firstarg or not.

Is it possible ?

I tried shelve, its not working for me for some reason. I am not seeing any logs written to the file.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to store these values for each unique user? or are these application level variables? Also, is this going to be run from the same server each time or does each user have a copy of the app and you are logging for each user that way?

Comment: Please post your code so people can examine and help.

Comment: Its a command line app. Each user will run on their machine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say use a JSON file as a persistent store and use the `load` and `dump` methods for reads and writes.
The JSON method is built in so all you need is to import it and use it:

```
import json

data_file = '/path/to/file'
# Load current state from file
contents = json.load(data_file)
# Do something
# ....
# ....
# Change values
contents['firstarg'] = firstarg
# Save to file
json.dump(contents, data_file)
```

Since you don't have a code sample, this is a simple approach